# Odoo 11.0 Try to replace the view of forecasted button, javascrip error

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-11

I replaced the action of the forecasted button with an xpath,
I setted as name of the button my new action *action_stock_level_forecast_report_product_tree*

And in my action I have setted the ref of my new view *product_product_forecast_tree_view*

```
    <!--product product -->
    <record id="product_product_forecast_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.forecast.tree.view</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="test">
                <!--<field name="product_id"/>-->
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_stock_level_forecast_report_product_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Stock Level Forecast Report product Tree</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.product</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_product_forecast_tree_view"/>
    </record>

    <record id="product_product_forecasted_button" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.product.forecasted.button</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(stock.action_stock_level_forecast_report_product)d']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="name">%(action_stock_level_forecast_report_product_tree)d</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Then i tried to run this, but i have got a strange JavaScript error :

> Erreur: TypeError: list is undefined
>
> http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1193
>   Retraçage :
>   _applyX2ManyOperations@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1193:194
>   get@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1124:565
>   get/list.data<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1128:169
>   _.collect@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:13:270
>   get@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1128:126
>   renderSidebar@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:1688:85
>   renderSidebar@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:3013:502
>   OdooClass.extend/Class.include/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:3819:368
>   render_view_control_elements@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:489:76
>   _display_view@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:483:261
>   switch_mode/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:482:44
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:678
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   Deferred/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:803:56
>   switch_mode/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:481:395
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   add@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:797:467
>   switch_mode/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8507-ea13d16/web.assets_backend.js:481:338
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:678
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   updateFunc/<@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:804:482
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   Deferred/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:803:56
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   add@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:797:467
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:772
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   Deferred/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:803:56
>   rpc/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:3869:346
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:678
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   Deferred/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:803:56
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   then/http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:802:874
>   fire@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:796:281
>   fireWith@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:801:198
>   done@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:1192:86
>   callback@http://localhost:8069/web/content/8496-d085622/web.assets_common.js:1212:15

Can someone help me please ?
Sorry for the mistakes I'm french and I'm a begginner with odoo/python/xml

Comment: Try adding some fields into your tree view. I'm not certain, but it's possible the error is occurring because the tree is empty.

Comment: oh it was the solution, how can I set your comment as the answer ?

Comment: I added as an answer so you can accept and close the question. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tree view must have some content in order to be rendered. Add at least one field in your view and it should load normally.

```
<record id="product_product_forecast_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.forecast.tree.view</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="test">
            <!-- Needs real content in the tree element -->
            <field name="product_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```